# Can WebRTC.io on server side (nodejs) access the stream?

Tags: html, node.js, webrtc

My plan is to stream voice from browser to the server (which would be Peer) in WebRTC :

I am making a nodejs server and client with webrtc.io like in the following link:
https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io

Since webRTC.io has a nodejs module, and (as I understood) claims to be a ported version of WebRTC in NodeJS, can the server do something like ?:

```
 rtc.on('add remote stream', function(stream){
    // show the remote video
    rtc.attachStream(stream, 'remote');
  });
```

I mean, can the WebRTC.IO server side be triggered when a remote stream is created? as it'd be a peer in the P2P connection?

Also, I guess I could access RTCPeerConnection in the server side, then access the stream.

also

```
webRTC.on('*', function(){
    console.log("*");
});
```

is never triggered. any reason ?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this? :)

Comment: Hi, no,  I gave up and went for Kurento (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571044/how-to-record-webcam-and-audio-using-webrtc-and-a-server-based-peer-connection) for a POC but we eventually canceled this feature.