# How to save webRTC opus audio stream on server side using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, webrtc, opus

There are some solutions to save a raw usermedia audio stream on the server side but I want to save the webRTC encoded stream which has low channel bandwidth transmission. I think of a solution that I'm not sure about:

Connect server and client using webRTC, the stream from the client is encoded then by the browser, convert the stream to mp3/ogg for later usage on the server.
I found two server side nodejs webrtc implementations :

1- [licode](https://github.com/ging/licode)

2- [node-webrtc](https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc)

Is there any other solution or better idea for my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give a try to [kurento](http://www.kurento.org/)

I will just link you this post :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24960167/1032907

Answer (score 1):

you could give https://github.com/mido22/recordOpus a try,

I basically, capture user's microphone and convert the raw pcm data into opus packets, send it to server, convert back to `wav` format, also provided the option of converting to `mp3` and `ogg` using `ffmpeg`.

Comment: looks great , the bandwidth is nearly the same as native solution (I couldn't handle stream bitrate), there need to be more document on the project about configurations , it seems better solution but by now kurento is more stable one until then , I hope I can help on the project , thank you :)

Comment: I know I am lagging behind in the configuration part, more than happy to take help, just fork the project and make a pull request, and it ll be done.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently successfully set up an [OpenVidu](https://openvidu.io) server on Ubuntu for recording video and audio, which runs the Kurento Media Server under the hood, and offers a host of convenient API's. Running the OpenVidu server with their CloudFormation config is the easiest, which takes care of SSL setup, running the docker container necessary for recording, etc.