# Firefox Audiocontext suspended

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-audio-api, audiocontext, recorder.js

I am trying to record audio and upload it to server using javascript.I am using Recorder js by Matt Diamond.But the issue is file getting generated is of 0 mins. When debugged through firebug console found out the audiocontext property was suspended. When googled found out for recording the audiocontext's state should be in running state. Don't know exactly if the issue is because of state or am I missing on something. Wanted to know what causes the state of audiocontext to be in suspended mode. If I try on other browsers the state is running and file is getting generated. But my restriction is I want to use firefox for my application

Firefox version: 42.0

Below is the code

```
if(audioRecorder)
{
 audioRecorder.clear();
 audioRecorder.record();

 setTimeout(stopRecorder,9000);   // 9 secs 
}
function stopRecorder()
{
  if(audioRecorder)
    {
       audioRecorder.stop();
       audioRecorder.exportWAV(function(blob){
       alert("Blob size : "+blob.size);
       // code for sending the blob to server 

          });
     }
}
```

when debugged the above code in firebug audiocontext was suspended.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this is not a direct answer, but it solves the issue, taken from my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36783739/3074768), if all you need is to send audio files to server, instead of using bulky uncompressed `wav` files, you can easily( and native-ly) record the audio in compressed `ogg` format using [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder), supported in firefox since v25 and chrome since v47.

Answer (score 0):

Created a JSFiddle and tested it a few times - works correctly on Firefox 42 [macosx]

- https://jsfiddle.net/8unmn650/

---

```
function createDownloadLink() {
   recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
     var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     var li = document.createElement('li');
     var au = document.createElement('audio');
     var hf = document.createElement('a');
     au.controls = true;
     au.src = url;
     hf.href = url;
     hf.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
     hf.innerHTML = hf.download;
     li.appendChild(au);
     li.appendChild(hf);
     recordingslist.appendChild(li);
});
```

---

- [RecorderJS demo](https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html) seems to be working correctly on FF 42 [macosx]

---

- There is an open issue on [recorder.js github repo](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20firefox) regarding Firefox browser creating 0s wav files

> [Issue 139](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/issues/139) Sometimes it is creating wav file of 0.0 duration on firefox #139