# how to make a video in django through forms?

Tags: opencv, django-forms, django-rest-framework, pycharm, video-capture

So, I'm creating a django form where I need to record video(contains audio also) from the webcam and later use it in machine learning.
So, as of now I've successfully install & using opencv to record videos.but this opencv instructions are written in  python file. so I want to integrate it with my django form.so that when an User opens my form & clicks on a button to record a video, directly Opencv opens and start recording it and get save in a server.
I'm using pycharm for this project.

Comment: The first problem you need to solve is "How can my OpenCV code running on a web server connect and read data from a webcam connected to the client machine accessing the website."

Comment: yes.any help from your side?

Comment: That itself is rather broad problem, and a lot of research and decisions for you to make. It will likely involve other technologies than what you listed (you quite likely need to write/run scripts to run in the browser) You need to work on adding detail to your requirements/specification and break the problem into smaller pieces to solve one at a time. | A brief search gives me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571044/how-to-record-webcam-and-audio-using-webrtc-and-a-server-based-peer-connection?rq=1) as a sample of what you likely need to solve before OpenCV on server comes to play