# Difference between webrtc and simplewebrtc

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, audio-recording, video-recording, simplewebrtc

I am getting confused about webrtc and simplewebrtc. What is the difference between both of them?

I want some extra functionalities aside from video/audio streaming. I want to record the remote or local videos. Please tell me which one is better to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebRTC](https://www.callstats.io/blog/the-beginners-guide-to-understanding-webrtc-in-3-minutes) enables peer-to-peer, real-time communication in web browsers and mobile applications through application programming interfaces. It is open source and free to use. It lets you integrate audio, video, screen sharing, and data transfers into your RTC app.

[SimpleWebRTC](https://www.simplewebrtc.com/) combines WebRTC and React to, presumably, make it easier for you to develop WebRTC applications. It has a free developer version and a paid version available. If you are a React dev, this will make things a lot simpler for you to use WebRTC to integrate audio, video, screen sharing, or data transfers into your RTC app.

So in answer to your question, the difference is not in the underlying technology for delivering audio and video, but in the way you develop for it. WebRTC is just WebRTC. SimpleWebRTC is using React to implement WebRTC.

As far as recording a WebRTC stream is concerned, there is a different, in-depth question on StackOverflow [that recommends using Kurento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571044/how-to-record-webcam-and-audio-using-webrtc-and-a-server-based-peer-connection).

It might be valuable for you to check out these [4 recommended ways to learn WebRTC](https://www.callstats.io/blog/2018/06/04/4-highly-recommended-ways-to-learn-webrtc).