# Ant Media Server save p2p video stream

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming, ant-media-server-sdk

I am new at media streaming, i am using ant-media server for p2p connection. is there any way to save stream data in my local storage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

P2P connection communicates between clients. Ant Media Server P2P connection is used only for signaling. You need to record streams client layer. I have added some examples of your requirements:

[How to record webcam and audio using webRTC and a server-based Peer connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571044/how-to-record-webcam-and-audio-using-webrtc-and-a-server-based-peer-connection)

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/mediarecorder

https://mozdevs.github.io/MediaRecorder-examples/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. :)) all references are web solution can you give me some references for mobile as well?

Comment: Does Mobile mean native SDK or Mobile browser?