# Broadcasting via server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

Hello everyone im trying to create a webcam broadcast via a server and i was wondering if there is a free away to do so maybe html5 or something and it doesn't have to support all browsers just chrome is sufficient.

I have tried ustream but the delay was incredibly long.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: High latency is the reality of broadcast-like streams.  If you're only streaming with a few users, look into WebRTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at WebRTC: everything is explained in this [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/). However there are considerations to be aware of about WebRTC and broadcasting notions. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507542/webrtc-live-audio-streaming-broadcast) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318983/webrtc-scalable-broadcasting).

Other than that you can use flash with either Flash Media Server or Wowza Media Server but it is not an immediate implementation and is paid otpion.