# RTP to WebRTC or WebSocket

Tags: node.js, websocket, webrtc, rtp

I've walkie-talkies sending the speech via RTP (G711a) into my LAN. My goal now is to take this audio-stream and provide it (one-to-many) to different Web-Clients. My preferred solution is to do this via WebRTC, but I can't find the right tools to deal with. My favorite environment is Node.js and C/C++.
Anybody out there who can help me, to find the right entry/the tools for this task?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507542/webrtc-live-audio-streaming-broadcast

Comment: All examples are using onboard mic or camera - my problem is, that I've an external source (RTP-Stream)  I'd like to relay to the peer ...

Comment: WebRTC was designed for a peer2peer network, while you will have a server-client design. I'm not sure why you prefer WebRTC, but if you're seeking to use the best took for the job, I think Websockets would fit best.